# Запятая в выражении "более чем в три раза"

Tags: запятая

Нужна ли запятая в выражении "более чем в три раза"? Спасибо.

Comment: Cпасибо, Виктор! Не поясните, почему запятая не ставится? Это не сравнение?

Answer (score 3):

Если выражения БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ или НЕ МЕНЕЕ ЧЕМ можно заменить словами «как минимум; самое меньшее; и даже больше», то запятая не ставится.

Ср.: ***Вы были для меня больше чем другом = Вы были для меня другом, даже больше.
Ср. также: Водка была горькая, разведенная, по случаю праздника, водой более чем на три четверти. В. Короленко, Сон Макара (= как минимум на три четверти, самое меньшее на три четверти, на три четверти и даже больше). Таким образом тайна была сохранена более чем полудюжиною заговорщиков. А. Пушкин, Метель(=полудюжиною и даже больше).***

Наречное выражение и слова в составе сопоставительного оборота. [подробно здесь](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/70/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5___%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%28%2C%29_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

**В вашем случае запятая не ставится, так как значение выражения БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ В ТРИ РАЗА  = значению выражения "в три раза и даже больше".**

Answer (score 1):

В таком выражении запятая перед "чем" не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

Обороты с союзом ЧЕМ отделяются запятой, если в предложении сравниваются или подразумеваются два понятия: "Шут необходим толпе более, чем герой" (М. Горький). "Поэт в России - больше, чем поэт" (Е. Евтушенко).

При отсутствии сравниваемых понятий мы имеем неразложимое словосочетание, после которого,  как правило, следует количественно-именное сочетание: более чем в три раза.